# How to add PresentationFramework.Aero theme to ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, themes, resourcedictionary

I want to add the PresentationFramework.Aero theme to my ResourceDictionary. 
The ResourceDictionary itself is in one assembly called ProjectResources. Within this assembly I define all my styles for my project. So this ResourceDictionary is used by several different assemblies in my project. So far it worked fine for all my Dictionaries defined.

Now i want to add the Aero theme. But I always get the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll

Inner Exception:

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework.Aero,
>   Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified.":"PresentationFramework.Aero, Culture=neutral"}

The ResourceDictionary is defined like that:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ProjectResources;component/ProjectResources/Dictionaries/ImageDefinition.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ProjectResources;component/ProjectResources/Dictionaries/Brushes.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ProjectResources;component/ProjectResources/Dictionaries/StylesLabel.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ProjectResources;component/ProjectResources/Dictionaries/StylesTextBox.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ProjectResources;component/ProjectResources/Dictionaries/StylesButton.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ProjectResources;component/ProjectResources/Dictionaries/StylesTabControl.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ProjectResources;component/ProjectResources/Dictionaries/StylesTextBox.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ProjectResources;component/ProjectResources/Dictionaries/StylesBorder.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ProjectResources;component/ProjectResources/Dictionaries/StylesListView.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ProjectResources;component/ProjectResources/Dictionaries/StylesWindow.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ProjectResources;component/ProjectResources/Dictionaries/StylesIndicator.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ProjectResources;component/ProjectResources/Dictionaries/StylesSearchBox.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ProjectResources;component/ProjectResources/Dictionaries/StylesTreeView.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero;component/themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

I have also added the reference to PresentationFramework.Aero.dll.

So I don't understand why it cant find the defined theme.
What is the problem with this definition? Did I miss anything else beside this definition to be able to use the theme?

**SOLVED:**
As toumir said in his comment.
You need to set the parameter

> Copy Local = true

of the PresentationFramework.Aero DLL.
By doing that the dll will be copied to the root directory of your program and it will the dll.

Comment: are you copied the PresentationFramework.Aero.dll into your current execution directory? or set to true to CopyLocal to the dll when you reference it

Comment: @toumir: Thx a lot. What a stupid mistake. I tried a lot of things. But i really forgot to set "Copy Local" to true.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the full assembly info to the ResourceDictionary Source:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero,Version=3.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,processorArchitecture=MSIL;component/themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml" />
```

Comment: Explanation of why this is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8185946/3195477